# Google Calendar Integration with Flask

Tags: python, flask, google-calendar-api

I am just getting started out with Google Calendar API Integrations with Flask. I am using Flask's database and login system, so I am unsure how to integrate events with google calendar. In my app, the user will have a date and time and can confirm or deny the calendar appointment. If they accept the appointment, I have two ideas to happen:

1. I want it to prompt them to integrate it into their google calendar and they have to log in, etc. and it takes it to the Google Calendar page OR

2. I could potentially get their OAuth token and save them.

I am unsure how to do either. For reference, here is my code:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)   

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User({self.email}, {self.username})"
...   

{% for appointment in requested_appointments %}
    <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('accept', month=appointment.month, day=appointment.day, year=appointment.year, hour=appointment.hour, minute=appointment.minute) }}">All</a>
{% endfor %}

...

def accept(month, day, year, hour, minute):
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute() #based on events received
    # integrate into google --> takes them google calendar and prompts them
```

I am unsure about the best way to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: most APIs should have description how to access other user data. Program has to redirect user to Google page, user should login to Google, Google should ask if user confirm access to his data, Google should send back special `token` to url defined when you created API key/secret, and this token let you access data of this user. For every user you get separated token which you have to keep somewhere and use next time - and user will not have to login again to Google.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is an API: [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar)
You can also use it to access private calendars.
But I don't know this API and never used it, so I can not really help with that..

For your second idea, you can also use the Flask-OAuth extension.
The documentary could help you with that: [enter link description here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/)

[EDIT]
In fact there is also a resource from Google, where it is explained how to bind with Python to their API's. You should check the links: [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python)